# Access to Quartus II beta

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, quartus-ii

My FPGA card (a BittWare card, datasheet available [here](ftp://ftp.bittware.com/documents/data_sheets/ds-s5phq.pdf)) comes with example designs which require Quartus II 14 (beta). I cannot find where the beta versions of Quartus II can be downloaded from the Altera website.

Where can I download beta versions of Quartus II, specifically Quartus II 14 (beta)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked my local Altera distributor and they will send me a DVD with the "Customer Beta".

Answer (score 2):

I use "Altera software depot" for early releases: https://software.altera.com/ although the latest I can see is 13.1.4 Build 182 (Thu 13 Mar 2014) so you might need to speak to your Altera rep, or raise a support ticket to get a private download link.